# fadeIn working on hover but not onClick/click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, hover, fadein

Showing sublist items fades in on `hover()`, but not `click()` or `onclick()`.
http://jsfiddle.net/gymbry/mgMK4/

Comment: jQuery object doesn't have `onclick` method.

Comment: [Full answer with `commented` explinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335942/fadein-working-on-hover-but-not-onclick-click#answer-20336016)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
$('ul li').click(function (e) { //  jQuery click event. The "e" is the "event" argument
    e.stopPropagation();    //  prevents a parent elements "click" event from fireing (useul here since this asigns to inner li's as well)
    var ul = $(this).children('ul');    //  find any children "ul" in this li
    //  check if ul exist and toggle (not completely neccesary as jquery will simply preform no action if element is not found)
    if (ul.length) ul.fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

## Working Example

---

```
$('ul li').click(function (e) { //  jQuery click event. The "e" is the "event" argument
    e.stopPropagation();    //  prevents a parent elements "click" event from fireing (useul here since this asigns to inner li's as well)
    var ul = $(this).children('ul');    //  find any children "ul" in this li
    if (ul.length) {    //  check if ul exist
        if (ul.is(':visible')) {    //  check ul is visible
            ul.fadeOut('fast');
        }
        else {
            ul.fadeIn('fast');
        }
    }
});
```

## Example 2

---

Keep in mind, the above solution doesn't deal with siblings or deeper menus being open upon close. For a more full solution, try the following:

```
$('ul li').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var ul = $(this).children('ul');

    $(this).siblings().each(function(i) {
        var ul = $(this).children('ul');
        if (ul.length) if (ul.is(':visible')) {
            ul.find('ul').fadeOut('fast');
            ul.fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });

    if (ul.length) {
        if (ul.is(':visible')) {
            ul.find('ul').fadeOut('fast');
            ul.fadeOut('fast');
        }
        else ul.fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

## Example 3

Comment: Seems too elaborate for the specific case provided.

Comment: @BramVanroy I wasn't finished editing answer. And the OP doesn't seem to have a strong grasp of what is going on, thus the break down of more elaborate solutions. Also, a simple solution will not account for a lot of possible "problems" that will arise, such as dealing with sibling menus

Comment: I see. After update: upvoted.